# Kubernetes Try to add jenkins to a cluster

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

I'm begginer in Kubernetes and I try to add jenkins to my cluster.

When I run : `kubectl get ns`

```
NAME              STATUS   AGE
srv-dev           Active   77d
```

I try to deploy Jenkins on this cluster with this yaml file :

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: jenkins-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: jenkins
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: jenkins
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: jenkins
        image: srv-dev/jenkins:lts
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
volumeMounts:
          - name: jenkins-home
            mountPath: jenkins_home
      volumes:
        - name: jenkins-home
          emptyDir: {}
```

and with this command : `kubectl create -f config_jenkins.yaml --namespace srv-dev`
but I have always the same error :

```
error: error parsing config_jenkins.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 22: did not find expected key
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to correct your YAML; the alignment matters a lot in YAML.
Also, extensions/v1beta1 needs to be apps/v1 if the kind is Deployment

Try this -

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: jenkins-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: jenkins
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: jenkins
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: jenkins
        image: srv-dev/jenkins:lts
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
        volumeMounts:
          - name: jenkins-home
            mountPath: jenkins_home
      volumes:
        - name: jenkins-home
          emptyDir: {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your yaml file should be like this

```
apiVersion: apps/v1       # -------------This 
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: jenkins-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: jenkins
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: jenkins
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: jenkins
        image: srv-dev/jenkins:lts
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        volumeMounts:             #-------this
        - name: jenkins-home
          mountPath: jenkins_home
      volumes:
      - name: jenkins-home
        emptyDir: {}
```